# Importing data from json file to R

Tags: json, r

I have Json file and I am trying to import the data into R Studio
I installed rjson and jsonlight library
, I used this command

```
game1 <- fromJSON("/Users/ludn/Desktop/game1.json")
```

But I got this error

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
        "challenge0Time" : "2.8" } {   "challenge0" : [     {     
                 (right here) ------^
```

What is the problem?

Comment: try fromJSON(paste(readLines(/Users/ludn/Desktop/game1.json), collapse=""))

Comment: Have you tried to check if the JSON is correct? https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Besides, this is not really a reproducible example and we can only guess what goes wrong. Try cleaning up your json file until it is small enough to post it here (~few lines, no MBs). Usually you already find your mistake by trying to create a reproducible example. This is because you can pinpoint the exact issue.

Comment: Yes my json file is correct

Comment: actually it was working before

Comment: @user3490634, in that case I refer again to my previous comment on the reproducible example. Without it, it is difficult for us to help you since we cannot reproduce your error and it seems dependent on the input in game1.json. There are some great tips in the first answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Linux users (with systemd), here is a reproducible example of a similar problem (same sort of error message) I discovered when trying to parse my system logs: `tmp <- timefile(); system2("journalctl", c("--no-pager", "--output json"), stdout = tmp); library(jsonlite); jrnl <- read_json(tmp)`.