# Plotting data from json file on Rstudio

Tags: json, r

I have a json file:

```
{
"challenge0" : [
{
  "X" : "-15.5820999145508",
  "time" : "1489079614.50596",
  "Speed" : "Optional(__C.CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0))",
  "Y" : "-10.6790924072266"
},
{
  "X" : "-15.5820999145508",
  "time" : "1489079615.39075",
  "Speed" : "Optional(__C.CGVector(dx: 3.3732881377091e-08, dy: 5.58793544769287e-07))",
  "Y" : "-10.6790924072266"
},
{
  "X" : "-15.5917558670044",
  "time" : "1489079615.40559",
  "Speed" : "Optional(__C.CGVector(dx: -0.772350311279297, dy: 2.60296104670488e-07))",
  "Y" : "-10.6790924072266"
},
{
  "X" : "-15.6142683029175",
  "time" : "1489079615.42163",
  "Speed" : "Optional(__C.CGVector(dx: -1.54341471195221, dy: 2.79396772384644e-07))",
  "Y" : "-10.6790924072266"
},
"challenge1Time" : "2.24",

"challenge4Time" : "9.98",

 "TotalTime" : 24.17413234710693,

"challenge0Time" : "1.52"
```

How can I plot the challenge Times on one plot?

What I mean, I want a chart that has 2 dimensions:

```
x: Challenge times
y: Time
```

I am using Rstudio.

Comment: did you resolve your [other issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42909047/5977215) and imported your JSON into R?

Comment: And the example you've given here is not valid JSON.

Comment: No I have not resolved the problem yet? why is not valid json??  this json file is generated from swift language

Comment: It looks like it's been edited; there are missing brackets. [Try it out at here](http://jsonlint.com/). The go through [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5977215)